# tidyverse method for reading CSV section

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse, readr

Scenario: You have a CSV file with data in sections, e.g.

> [Car data]
>
> mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb
>
> > 21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
> >
> > 21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
> >
> > 22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
> >
> > 21.4,6,258,110,3.08,3.215,19.44,1,0,3,1
> >
> > 18.7,8,360,175,3.15,3.44,17.02,0,0,3,2
> >
> > 18.1,6,225,105,2.76,3.46,20.22,1,0,3,1
> >
> > 14.3,8,360,245,3.21,3.57,15.84,0,0,3,4  ...
> >
> > [Other stuff]

Forgive the formatting. I had to add extra new lines to get the block quoting to at least resemble the intended data format. I'll create a reproducible example using mtcars below and pretend we've done the easy bit of subsetting the rows we want, for example as per the motivating code quoted here:

```
# Import raw data:
data_raw <- readLines("test.txt")

# find separation line:
id_sep <- which(data_raw=="")

# create ranges of both data sets:
data_1_range <- 4:(id_sep-1)
data_2_range <- (id_sep+4):length(data_raw)

# using ranges and row data import it:
data_1 <- read.csv(textConnection(data_raw[data_1_range]))
data_2 <- read.csv(textConnection(data_raw[data_2_range]))
```

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628680/how-to-import-a-csv-file-containing-multiple-sections-into-r). In other words, the approach we're looking at adopting is to read the data in once, as lines, find the lines we want, and then "read" them using read.csv to get a data.frame.

Okay, so the year is now 2017 and we want to embrace the tidyverse world and use read_lines in place of readLines, and read_csv in place of read.csv.

```
library(tidyverse)

write_csv(mtcars, "mtcars_local.csv")
# this creates an easily reproduced local file

data_raw <- readLines("mtcars_local.csv")
# henceforth assume we've found the desired rows and subsetted

data_df <- read.csv(textConnection(data_raw))

head(data_df)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# whoo hoo, the above is exactly the output we want (replicating
# the original post answer)

data_raw_2 <- read_lines("mtcars_local.csv")

data_df_2 <- read_csv(textConnection(data_raw_2))
#Error in read_connection_(con) : 
#  Evaluation error: can only read from a binary connection.
```

So read_csv doesn't like taking a textConnection like read.csv did.
The documentation for read_csv does say:

> Arguments:
>
> ```
> file: Either a path to a file, a connection, or literal data
>       (either a single string or a raw vector).
> ```

So, question(s):

1. Is there a neat tidyverse way of getting a particular delimited section of a CSV into a tibble? (that doesn't involve reading in the lines and subsetting as an interim step)
2. Or from such a vector of strings of each line, how can you get them into a tibble?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a single string of data with rows separated by the required newline:

```
paste0(data_raw, collapse = "\n") [1] "mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb\n21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4\n21,6,160,110,...

data_df_2 <- read_csv(paste0(data_raw, collapse = "\n"))

head(data_df_2)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
2  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
```

Okay, et voila. In writing this post I've come up with an answer. But the use of paste seems klunky. Maybe I've been spoilt by reading about the glue package. But is there a "tidy"er way of getting a section of data from a CSV into a tibble?